# Ordering and grouping SQL Table by Timestamp in Ascending order?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Have a table that looks like this:

```
name_unique location  timestamp_test
jon         london   2019-01-01 18:26:21.780+00  
fred        chicago  2018-07-06 15:24:17.689+00
sam          paris   2019-10-30 03:12:06.421+00
jon         london   2019-01-01 17:26:21.780+00
fred        chicago  2018-07-06 00:00:00.000+00
```

I would like to group/order the data by name_unique and timestamp_test column - I am having some trouble in getting the order correct on the timestamp column.

My main problem is some rows have a timestamp record as year-month-day 00:00:00.000+00 - this should be the first record in the order by statement if done in ascending order (dates going upwards) - however my code seems to just throw all the dates in any order.

I would like to get the final table in this form:

```
name_unique location  timestamp_test 
fred        chicago  2018-07-06 00:00:00.000+00
fred        chicago  2018-07-06 15:24:17.689+00
jon         london   2019-01-01 17:26:21.780+00
jon         london   2019-01-01 18:26:21.780+00 
sam          paris   2019-10-30 03:12:06.421+00
```

As you can now see 'fred' from 'chicago' whose timestamp is 00:00:00.000+00 appears first because he is at midnight of that day. the name_unique values are in the alphabetical order and timestamp_test column is in correct order ascending - dates and times increase as records increase.

my current code is

```
select * 
from 
my_table 
order by name_unique, timestamp_test ASC
```

But no luck in ordering it correctly! any ideas? I am using postgresql and pgadmin4

Comment: Your code should be doing what you want.

Comment: It seems to be ignoring the order by timestamp_test ASC call - i am unsure as to why it is not working

Comment: "the name_unique values are in the alphabetical order and timestamp_test column is in correct order ascending" - you can't do both at the same time, surely?

Comment: "no luck in ordering it correctly!" is not a problem description. What output do you get, and why is that wrong.

Comment: Yeah I think we need to see the output you're getting to make any sense of this